How to substring in AngualrJS tag before printing the HTML output
I'm new to TypeScript and AngularJS.
The following code will print a list of "<div>"s by using TypeScript:
{{#if styles}}
  <h2 class="box-header">Styles</h2>
  <div class="box">
  {{#each styles}}
    <div class="item">
      {{#if thumbnail}}
        <img src="{{public_url}}styles/{{@key}}/{{thumbnail}}{{&../key_query}}" alt="{{name}} preview" />
      {{else}}
        <img src="{{public_url}}images/placeholder.png{{&key_query}}" alt="{{name}} preview" />
      {{/if}}
      <div class="details">
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <p class="identifier">identifier: {{@key}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/if}}

Here is the identifier line:
<p class="identifier">identifier: {{@key}}</p>

The output in HTML is one of the following values:
identifier: base_name
identifier: example_000_0_name_1
identifier: example_000_1_name_2
identifier: example_000_2_name_3
identifier: example_000_3_name_4
identifier: example_000_4_name_5

I want to remove the prefix "example_000_[n]_" when generating the identifier HTML:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typescript-string-substring-method/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angularjs/
<p class="identifier">identifier: substring({{@key}}, len("example_000_0_"))</p>

The expected output is:
identifier: base_name
identifier: name_1
identifier: name_2
identifier: name_3
identifier: name_4
identifier: name_5

The identifier line is not javascript code, so I don't know if it is possible to substring inside the "{{}}" variable.
I tried: {{@key.substr(3)}}:
Error: Parse error on line 35:
...>identifier: {{@key.substr(3)}}</p>    
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Also tried: identifier: {{("" + @key).substr(3)}}
Error: Parse error on line 35:
...fier">identifier: {{("" + @key).substr(3
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'OPEN_SEXPR'

How to substring the "{{@key}}" in "<p class="identifier">identifier: {{@key}}</p>"?

To run javascript "inside" the view element you need to put the javascript code inside the interpolation markup {{here}}.
One option, instead of writing a complex substring which would need to take into account that numbers are more than one digit, is to use Split() on the underscore instead.
It would look something like this:
<p class="identifier">identifier: {{@key.split('_')[3]}}_{{@key.split('_')[4]}}</p>

Here's a working plunkr
